# WordPress rewrite rule in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have te following htacces snippet in the wordpress's htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/
RewriteRule css/style.min.css$ /minify/minify.php?dir=%{REQUEST_URI}&file=style.css [L]
```

Which redirects the following:

```
https://something.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/style.min.css
```

to:

```
https://something.com/minify/minify.php?dir=/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/&file=style.css
```

How can I get the same effect with `add_rewrite_rule`?

---

**Update 2**

So what I want is: my wordpress is in folder `wordpress`, which is in the root. But I use my wordpress page from `https://something.com/main`, so I followed the guide on the wordpress page and it works. What I want is, I have assets files in my theme folder like `/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/style.css`.

I want a php function like:

```
<img src="<?php echo myRoute("/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/css/global_stylesheet_file.css", "/home/assets/css/style.css"); ?>" />
```

which returns to the html like `https://something.com/main/assets/css/style.css` but creates a htaccess or a route for this to access the original file

Comment: Rwrite rules in htaccess are far more efficient and quicker than rewrites done via WordPress.

Comment: @PhillHealey I want to access my files like `https://something.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/style.css` from the url `https://something.com/wordpress/assets/style.css`. I want to make a dynamic htacces converter function which like `<a href="<?php echo make_route(assets/style.css); ?>`. It returns the shorter URL but saves and adds the RewriteRule to the htaccess automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: It sounds like your best option would be to use a regex to take care of this. Then its just one line in your htaccess file that would take care of all your redirects, without any extra work.

Comment: @PhillHealey Could you please help? Im not into htaccess, not even regex.

Comment: I still don't understand what you need, sorry. Is there a fixed pattern that these url rewrites follow?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your best option would be to use a regex to take care of this. Then its just one line in your htaccess file that would take care of all your redirects, without any extra work.

Something like this might work:

RedirectMatch 301 wp-content/themes/mytheme/cs‌​s/style.css assets/$1 It sounds like your best option would be to use a regex to take care of this. Then its just one line in your htaccess file that would take care of all your redirects, without any extra work.

Something like this should work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 https://something.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/cs‌​s/$1 https://something.com/wordpress/assets/(.*)
```

or, if you want to do it the otherway:

```
RedirectMatch 301 https://something.com/wordpress/assets/$1 https://something.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/cs‌​s/(.*)
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working when I use it with the same filename. But what should I do when I want to redirect `https://something.com/wordpress/assets/othername.css` to `https://something.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/originalname.css`? Also dinamically.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand. I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not what I exactly wanted. I updated my post, could you please help me again?